# Firebase Analytics iOS

Tags: ios, swift, events, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an event "my_event" with two custom parameters "parameter_one" and "parameter_two", both kind of text. 
But when I log the event it doesn't appear on the table.

That's what I'm trying:

```
Analytics.logEvent("my_event", parameters: ["parameter_one": "value_of_parameter_one"])
```

[table's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2g9n.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer.

From FIRParameterNames.h

> Params supply information that contextualize Events. You can associate up to 25 unique Params with each Event type. Some Params are suggested below for certain common Events, but you are not limited to these. You may supply extra Params for suggested Events or custom Params for Custom events. Param names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an alphabetic character. Param values can be up to 100 characters long. The "firebase" prefix is reserved and should not be used.

I was using the prefix "firebase_". Leaving my answer here if someone also chooses precisely this prefix.